# Retain Sort Order of Datagrid View after Updating SQL Adapter

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

As the title says, I am looking for a way to retain the sort order of my DataGridView after refreshing the data from SQL.

If I sort any of my columns, as soon as the data is refreshed, the columns are no longer sorted and the selected row I had is no longer selected.

Is there an easy solution that would be something along the lines of:

```
Dim NewSort as Something
SortOrder = DataGridView1
DataGridView1.Refresh
DataGridView1.SortOrder = NewSort
```

I know the above code is hypothetical but I would be pleased with any solution or to be pointed in the right direction. Google and Bing have not produced helpful resources.

Comment: An actual, proper refresh will not change the DGV sort or lose/change the current active row.  You might want to include the code used to "refresh" and "update" because they are likely to blame.

Comment: Do you have a resource to point me to as far as a "proper refresh" is concerned? I am connecting to sql through a sql data adapter and filling a data table that then becomes the data source to my datagridview. My "refresh" is simply calling the original function again (which runs the original sql query, fills the data table, then sets the data source on the datagridview.

Comment: As I suspected, you are not refreshing anything at all but creating a *new* DataSource.  I suggested that you update the post with the code so that your question could be answered - info, details or code in comments doesnt really could because it could disappear at any moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a sort, you do a database refresh and your sort is gone.  I've encountered this before.  I created an inherited grid to handle this, but there's the general idea.

Assuming you are binding to a DataView, consider this.

```
' Get the Sort
string currentSort = "";
if ( grid.DataSource != null )
    currentSort = ((DataView) grid.DataSource).Sort

' Reset the Data Source
grid.DataSource = yournewsource of data ' Better Be a Data View

' Recall the Sort
((DataView) grid.DataSource).Sort = currentSort
```

One thing I did was had an inherited grid where the data the DataSource Get property was overwritten to have this, and used the inherited grid throughout the application, rather than having to put this code everywhere.  It's easy enough to change to an inherited grid if you are comfortable going into the Designer file and editing.

```
public class MyDataGridView : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{


    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return base.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            string currentSort = "";
            if (!(base.DataSource == null))
                currentSort = ((DataView)base.DataSource).Sort;

            base.DataSource = value;
            ((DataView)base.DataSource).Sort = currentSort;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: changed to datagridview